# intermediate service implementation with security

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a simple WCF Client -> Server structure, where the client references the server's WCF service. Authentication is done using X509 certificates.

I want to add a simple form of redundancy to my service. Meaning- to have several servers running, and have the client use a router that would transparently fail-over to a backup server if the main one is dead.

I've looked at WCF 4.0 routing but [that was no good](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10121906/537913).

So what's left is to do that on my own. I've found [a nice example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29775/WCF-Intermediate-Service-between-Client-and-Server) that does just that.

However, the author did not use any security at all.

I've tried to add message-level security by adding the following to the router's `<client>` binding configuration (I copied it from my existing client's configuration):

```
<security mode="Message">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
   <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"  
            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
</security>
```

using this, I get a

> The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate
>   in ClientCredentials.

exception from my server.

So I manually added the certificate to the channel I create in my router's code (complete listing here):

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IntermediateServiceManager")]
public interface IIntermediateServiceContract
{
   [OperationContract(Name = "ProcessMessage", Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
   Message ProcessMessage(Message message);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class IntermediateServiceManager : IIntermediateServiceContract
{
    public Message ProcessMessage(Message requestMessage)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IIntermediateServiceContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IIntermediateServiceContract>("MyEndpoint");
        factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,StoreName.My,X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"mycert.company.com");
        IIntermediateServiceContract proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        IClientChannel clientChannel = proxy as IClientChannel;

        Message responseMessage = proxy.ProcessMessage(requestMessage);
        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```

and now the error I get is

> Multiple headers with name 'Security' and namespace
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'
>   and role '' found`.

I've turned on WCF diagnostic, and compared the headers of the message sent from the router with those sent from the client. and indeed, the router messages have 2 security headers.

I'm assuming one was originally added by the client (since it doesn't know that it's now working against a router- it still thinks that this is the actual server), and the second one by the router.

So, logically, the next thing to do is to disable the security I've added at first to the router configuration (simply changed `security mode` to `None`).

And now the exception I get is

> The 'To', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' required message
>   part  was not signed

I'm assuming this means that my router has changed the message's `To` field, and since no security was configured- the router didn't sign it...

So I guess I'm kind of stuck. The two options I'm currently considering are:

1. Somehow tamper with the message's headers and remove the redundant security header.
2. Disable security between the client and the router, and have security only between the router and the service.

This, however, has the disadvantage of having to change the client, which I don't want to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like the router does not really need to know that it gets soap. maybe you could just use a simple http receiver as the router? this will save you from all the duplicate security / header parsing stuff.

Comment: @Yaron you may be right. i'm not really familiar with http receivers; can you elaborate? also, can you reference the receiver the same way you reference a soap service? as i said, i'm reluctant to change my client.

Comment: check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx. you do not reference the router - you still reference the service, but just override the url in your config to go to the router. Unless of course you have some endpoint in your router that also pipes to the wsdl file. This may be some work, I only recommend this since you cannot change your client.